# How do I find what files have been modified in my local branch?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, version-control, tfs, azure-devops

I use Visual Studio 2013 with TFS.  There are multiple published branches.  I created a local branch from one of the branch and made some modifications.  I then committed my changes to my local branch.

...

I've created another local branch from one of the published branches and made changes to files in my second local branch and committed them locally.  I've not merged any files.

...

I've switched between the two local branches a number of times and commited multiple files.

...

1. So I can switch between my local/unpublished branches but is there a way to see what files have been modified for a given local/unpublished branch?

If I right click a branch a click view history, I can see the multi commits that I've made for that local branch and the files that correspond to each commit but is there a way to see a list of all the files that have been changed for that branch and not for each commit?

2. Also, how can I find out from what published branch the local/unpublished branch was created from?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the branch and choose "View History".

Comment: If I right click a branch a click view history, I can see the multi commits that I've made for that local branch and the files that correspond to each commit but is there a way to see a list of all the files that have been changed for that branch and not for each commit?

Comment: No, that's not how Git works. Git is based on commits. When you branch, you're just making a new pointer to a commit.